# Tengo problemas para obtener el numero de teléfono completo con intl tel input

Tags: javascript, jquery

libreria: https://intl-tel-input.com/

html

```
<input class="phone2" name="telefono" type="tel">
```

js

```
 var input = document.querySelector(".phone2");
window.intlTelInput(input, {
    // allowDropdown: false,
    autoHideDialCode: false,
    // autoPlaceholder: "off",
    // dropdownContainer: document.body,
    // excludeCountries: ["us"],
    // formatOnDisplay: false,
    // geoIpLookup: function(callback) {
    //   $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function() {}, "jsonp").always(function(resp) {
    //     var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
    //     callback(countryCode);
    //   });
    // },
    // hiddenInput: "full_number",
    initialCountry: "",
    // localizedCountries: { 'de': 'Deutschland' },
    // nationalMode: false,
    // onlyCountries: ['us', 'gb', 'ch', 'ca', 'do'],
    // placeholderNumberType: "MOBILE",
    separateDialCode: true,
    preferredCountries: ['pe'],
    utilsScript: "/plugin-telf/js/utils.js",
});
```

Si me carga el plugin por completo el listado de países con sus banderas y su código del pais pero al momento que selecciono el código e ingreso un numero de teléfono y envió el formulario solo me llegue el numero de teléfono, sin el código del país.

Imagenes Una es del input en la pagina web, y la otra es del registro en la tabla.
[image: Input en la web]

[image: Tabla]

Comment: gracias amigo conseguí una forma mas optima

Answer (score 0):

logre solucionar iniciando asi el js:

```
var input = document.querySelector(".phone2");
window.intlTelInput(input, {
    autoHideDialCode:false,
    nationalMode: false,
    preferredCountries: ['pe'],
    utilsScript: "/plugin-telf/js/utils.js",
});
```

agregando estas dos lineas

```
    autoHideDialCode:false,
    nationalMode: false,
```